# C++: Program skipping to the end

Tags: c++, dictionary, space

My aim was to store the words and its counts in a given string which has some space separations. I used map caching to count the repeated words and the logic seems to be good.
However,  I really not getting, whats wrong with it. It looks like, program skipping to the end and showing some junk output.
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T; cin>>T;
    for(auto t=0; t<T; ++t){
       string full;             // sentance/ string with spaces
       getline(cin,full);

       map<string, int> Map;    // word and its count 

       string strWords;
       strWords.clear();

       for (int i = 0; i<full.length(); i++)
       {
         if (full[i] == ' ')
         {
            Map[strWords]++;
            strWords.clear();   // clear it for next word
         }
         else
            strWords += full[i];// if there is no space, build word!
       }
         Map[strWords]++;       // for the last word in the string  

      for(auto &it: Map)
        cout<<it.first<<" "<<it.second<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example: for the input

```
1
yoy yoy koy koy
```

I am getting an output:

```
1
```

instead of

```
yoy 2
koy 2
```

Comment: Side note: you can simplify your code a lot with `std::istringstream`.

Comment: ignore(): thats what I missed. Thanks a lot for pointing out.